# How to draw a bottoming out curved trendline

Tags: python, matplotlib, trendline

I want to draw a trendline that follows a few points nicely. It is supposed to be a kind of 'average' so it doesn't have to hit the points exactly, but the shape has to be a smooth arc.
I am having trouble getting Python or Excel to get exactly what I want. Here is an example code that I'm using,

```
x = np.array([6,8,10,12,16,24,32])
y = np.array([934,792,744,710,699,686,681])

#create scatterplot
plt.scatter(x, y)

#calculate equation for quadratic trendline
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
p = np.poly1d(z)

#add trendline to plot
plt.plot(x, p(x))
```

which gives a output like [image: this]

whereas what I'm looking for is something like [image: this]
Here's another example, where the line is sharper and doesn't bottom out like the previous
[image]

Does anyone know how this can be done? When I try it on Excel it seems like an 'equation' is needed but I'm not sure how to get to this equation.

Edit: the curve I am looking for has to be monotonic decreasing and concave

Comment: Is there a known function that these points are approximating?

Comment: Also, the curve it gives you is a quadratic fit, which won't give you what you drew since that looks more like 1/x.

Comment: Have you tried increasing degree of the fitting polynomial from 2 to 3 or 4? Also, you could insert the average between 2 values so that it has more 'resolution'.

Comment: @jared No there are no known functions, and it doesn't need to follow a function for my purpose.

Comment: @jared, hey! Could you check my comment above? I'm just curious if these are the best approaches?

Comment: @doneforaiur I've tried increasing the polynomial order, but all it does also is add more inflection points.

Comment: @doneforaiur, adding data like that goes back to the original question of how you choose the value, so I would not recommend that.

Comment: @IanLow So what makes one fit better than the other? You chose a quadratic and the code gave you the best quadratic (as determined by least squares). What is it you actually want?

Comment: @doneforaiur that's how I would usually do it. I'd create a secondary 'trendline' plot with fake data. it is still ok for me since I'm forcing a certain shape anyway. But I would prefer if there was a neater way to do this

Comment: @jared the curve has to be monotonic decreasing, and concave.

Comment: @IanLow There are an infinite number of curves that satisfy those conditions.

Comment: @jared at the end, all curves will tend to a horizontal limit. This is clear in the first case. However in the second case, I do not have the data points to get to the limit yet.

Comment: @jared overall it seems I am looking for a 1/x + y kind of curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fit a curve with a desired shape, use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Since you want a generic `1/x` curve, you can use `a/(x+b) + c`, where `a` adjusts the curvature, `b` adjusts the left-right position, and `c` adjusts the up-down position. You can see how these parameters change the shape using [this Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xhvdtf20cf) plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

plt.close("all")

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a/(x+b) + c

x = np.array([6,8,10,12,16,24,32])
y = np.array([934,792,744,710,699,686,681])

popt, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)

xfine = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 50)
yfit = func(xfine, *popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, ".")
ax.plot(xfine, yfit)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job. but when run with the other data chunk x = np.array([4.75,5.15,5.9,6.7,7,7.95,10.2,12.2])
y = np.array([1007,982,888,876,870,832,754,781]), It throws an error Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800

Comment: Regarding the above comment, scaling the numbers down did the trick

Comment: @IanLow Giving it a good initial guess also helps. I tried `p0=(1000, -2, 700)` and it worked.